# Best practice when it comes to Creating Intents

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

I have a custom listview that displays approx. 114 items, and in it I have a TextView (use as a link) so when the user clicks on the link it takes to another activity something like "read more..." kinda of link within a listview.

my question: Is the code below is optimized? in other words following the best practices? or horrible? since I will be creating around 114 `activities`, `layouts` and adding in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row_custom_listview, null); 

    final TextView artist = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.artist);   
    TextView link = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.txtLink);  

    link.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(View v) {

    if (position == 0) {
       Intent intent_01 = new Intent(v.getContext(), more_01_Activity.class);    
       v.getContext().startActivity(intent_01); 
    }
    if (position == 1) {
       Intent intent_02 = new Intent(v.getContext(), more_02_Activity.class);    
       v.getContext().startActivity(intent_02); 
    }
    if (position == 3) {
       Intent intent_03 = new Intent(v.getContext(), more_03_Activity.class);    
       v.getContext().startActivity(intent_03); 
    }
         ...........
         ............
         ...........
         //goes upto 114 

        }
    }); 
    return vi;
}
```

Comment: I would describe that as extremely scary, and not good whether or not Intents were involved.  First off, how similar are more_01_Activity, more_02_Activity, and so on?  If you could pass an argument to them, such as the position, would they be identical?

Comment: so in the `more_01_activity/02/03....` i will be displaying the text, so answer to your question yes completely different.

Comment: If the text is the only difference, then you can just pass the stringId of the text to show and have one activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
findViewById
```

is a very expensive call which should be avoided as much as possible, fortunately there's this idea of a `ViewHolder`, which you can use like this:

create an inner class called ViewHolder

```
private class ViewHolder {
  TextView link;
}
```

then inside your getView,

```
ViewHolder viewHolder;
if(convertView==null) {
  convertView = inflater.inflate...
  viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
  viewHolder.link = convertView.findViewById...
  convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
} else {
  viewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
}
```

After that, it's just a matter of using the holder items instead of the TextView `link` variable.
so

```
viewHolder.link.setOnClickListener...
```

Also, instead of creating hundreds of different activities, you can code a more flexible activity that can adjust itself depending on the information it receives from the intent that launches it. example:

inside onClickListener,

```
  Intent i = new Intent(context, MyFlexibleActivity.class);
  i.putExtra("position", position);
  startActivity(i);
```

To get the position in the receiving Activity, do

```
int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", default_value);
```

and work on that information to display what you're trying to accomplish with different activities.

If you have more questions, feel free to ask in the comments.

(update: string array example, from this [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html))
on your strings.xml, instead of just one string per item, you can have a string array:
    
    
        
            Mercury
            Venus
            Earth
            Mars

to use it,

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

Comment: thank you Josephus, one last question (hopefully) in the `MyFlexibleActivity` i am assuming that i have to have a `if conditions` to check the position and based on that display the activit? stringId of the text to show and have one activity? or may be i am thinking totally wrong, or can you post few lines of `MyFlexibleActivity` implementation?

Comment: what exactly do you want MyFlexibleActivity to look like? A List? just a String? If it's a String maybe you can just have an static array of strings (in your main activity, for instance) where you can query an item using the position you got from the intent.

Comment: i think you're getting this wrong. you shouldn't need hundreds of layout xml's - instead, make your layout flexible so that whatever you want to display (i'm assuming they just differ in whatever text or list they display). so tell us - in what ways are the 114 different activities different? maybe post some rough drawing/layout.

Comment: sorry, but still can't find the difference. can you be more specific as to what your app wants to accomplish? also, have you considered using a string-array instead? (will update my answer for string array example)

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to say but indeed it is horrible. What you can do is store `more_01_Activity.class` in an array or hash map or file.

**Soln:** Using array

```
static Class[] activityList = { more_01_Activity.class, more_02_Activity.class };

Intent intent_03 = new Intent(v.getContext(), activityList[position]);    
v.getContext().startActivity(intent_03);
```

You can also use reflection and if you do so then you can actually persist the position to activity mapping in a file and load it at startup.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a compiler right now, but you can try this.

I think it works but let me know if it don't.

```
    private List<Class> listOfActivityClass; // Add all your Activity.class into this list

    ......

        link.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
            public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent;
            intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), listOfActivityClass.get(position);

            if(intent != null) {
                v.getContext().startActivity(intent); 
            }

        });
```